# Can a pro se plaintiff call the defendant as a witness and compel testimony in a civil suit?

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure, maryland

I have a court case coming up in Maryland District Court. It is a landlord-tenant dispute; we are *pro se* plaintiffs and the defendants (husband and wife, both landlords to the house I lived at) will be represented by an attorney. There is another plaintiff in addition to myself, my former roommate.

The co-plaintiff and I would like to use direct and cross examination, however we are a bit confused on how to proceed.

Can we call the defendants as witnesses so we may cross examine them during the case in chief? Would we call the defendant as a witness before the case begins? Is doing this known as "compelling testimony" and is this even allowed if the defendants have a lawyer?

Can I direct examine my co-plaintiff?

I have read online it could be advantageous to perform the cross examination before the direct examination. Is this allowed? If so, does this mean I can ask the defendant questions before I ask the co-plaintiff questions?

I understand there are multiple sets of rules in regards to civil procedure, such as federal, state and even local.

Comment: About your case, could you clarify what you mean by "coming up"? at what stage is your lawsuit? are you sure, based on the amount involved, your case would not have to be litigated in the Small Claims court?

Comment: The trial is this week. It is a small claims case, but they are allowed to bring a lawyer. I accidentally wrote Circuit Court, meant to write District Court, edited it.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to convince you to at least consult a lawyer on these questions, if not just hire one to handle this for you? People in court pro se are already at such a disadvantage and judging by the questions you've posted above, I'd be concerned this will turn out as a massive waste of time for you at best, and a significant money drain at worst. I mean no offense by that; those are legit questions for non-lawyers to have. And again, that's why you're advised not to do this without a loser

Comment: Unfortunately it wouldn't be cost effective for us to hire a lawyer and the filing fees were pretty cheap. I have chatted with a few lawyers and hammered out the facts of the case, the general consensus is we do have a decent case. I have been to trial a few times (and been burned) and have learned from my mistakes. I feel we would be at a significant disadvantage if we didn't do any type of examination. I'm sure the judge will guide us somewhat, but I know judges are limited to what advice they can provide if any. I just want some general guidance on the examination process. Thank you

Comment: You say it's a small claims case. In at least one state, Minnesota, defendants must testify if the plaintiff questions them. And vice-versa.

Comment: What are you hoping to establish by examining your landlord as a witness?  Perhaps you can establish that without examining your landlord as a witness.

Comment: I am hoping to establish that the landlord gave us no notice of something they, in our opinion, should have told us about. I could not think of any evidence that would "prove" that the landlord didn't notify us of something (unless I show every email and text between the landlord and tenants and say "look Your Honor, they didn't notify us of that particular issue in any of the emails or texts"). I was thinking an examination would allow us to elicit a yes/no response to the question: Did you notify the tenants of this particular issue?

Comment: Hey @coffeeguy, I've actually heard - and this depends heavily on the attitudes of the particular court and simply various judges' personalities - of judges providing significant step-by-step help throughout a trial. Obviously, not providing any legal strategy, but rather guidance on procedural matters. I've also heard of just the opposite, with poor Mr. *Pro Se* left to sweat it out on his own. Here's hoping your judge is more the former and less the latter ;)

Comment: You could always establish that fact by testifying that they did not notify you, whereafter they would be expected to rebut your testimony, which could be difficult if they never in fact notified you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you may call a defendant as a witness and compel the defendant to testify in a civil case.

If you need this testimony to prove your case, you should have the clerk issue a subpoena for trial to the defendant and have that subpoena personally served by a process server upon that defendant (sometimes a witness fee, a mileage allowance, and a copy of the relevant statute must also be included in the package). There should be a standard court form available to do this. The subpoena to appear and testify at trial must be delivered to the defendant by the process server a certain amount of time in advance (usually two days, but court rules vary).

Also, when you call a defendant as a witness you may generally examine the witness with leading questions, which is something that you are not usually allowed to do with witnesses that you call in your own case.

Forcing a defendant to testify to the indisputable facts is a good way to meet your burden of proof towards establishing those facts. But, when you call a defendant as a witness, you should limit your questions to those you know the answer to and can ideally prove with other evidence if the defendant lies. Don't try to tell the entire story of the case with the defendant, just the undisputed facts.

The one narrow exception to this would be a criminal contempt of court proceeding (i.e. one seeking the remedy of throwing the offending party in jail where there is no way to obtain relief by taking the action requested) prosecuted by a party within a civil case, to which 5th Amendment protections would apply. But, this would not apply to the kind of case described in the original post.

Comment: I should have had the clerk issue a subpoena to both defendants to appear at the trial. The wife did not appear, only the husband. Questioning her was essential to proving our case.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the rules in Maryland, but generally speaking, a plaintiff may call the defendant as a witness, and vice versa. The fact that either side has lawyers has no bearing on this. Further, each side is generally permitted to choose the order in which it calls witnesses, so a plaintiff could call the defendant and then take the stand himself.

Note, though, that as a matter of trial strategy, this is generally considered a bad idea. You can read one discussion of this approach [here](https://www.butlerrubin.com/wp-content/uploads/December-2013-OP-Article.pdf).

In a *pro se* situation, I would imagine that a court would allow co-plaintiffs to examine each other, though I can also see reasons why it might require them to each testify independently -- primarily because neither is a lawyer and either one could unwittingly prejudice the others' rights.

Comment: The beginning of that article may have cleared up some things for me, although correct me if I'm wrong. If I call the defendant, regardless of order, and question them during my case in chief, it would be considered a direct examination of the defendant, not a cross examination? I was under the impression a direct examination only applies to witnesses for the plaintiff.

Comment: Direct examination is for witnesses you and your co-parties call, regardless of whether you're the plaintiff or defendant. Cross examination is is for witnesses your opposing party calls, regardless of whether you're the plaintiff or defendant. If the witness is aligned with an opposing party, it would normally be treated as a cross examination, even if it is technically a direct.

Comment: Calling the Defendant as a witness, often as a first witness is a case, is a quite common and desirable trial strategy. As I lawyer, I probably do so in about 50% of the trials that I litigate. The key is to combine that with only asking questions you know the answer to and want to get from that witness.

Comment: Yikes! That is ballsy and I love it. Not as bad when you've get a depo transcript in hand, obviously, but I'd still be wary of letting the defendant be the first person to tell my story.

Comment: I wanted to give a special thanks to you bdb484 for your definition of the terms in your first comment to your answer. You provide a much clearer explanation of the terms than many other online resources!

Answer (score 0):

A lawyer may call any (relevant) person as a witness, including someone on the opposite side. That includes the plaintiff's lawyer/prosecutor calling the defendant.

This is seldom done because by doing so, you have made this witness "your" witness, thereby meaningfully reducing your options. Normally, you wait for the other side to put the witness on the stand, and then "cross examine" him or her. So you would do this only if 1) there was a good chance that the defendant won't testify (so you don't get your "cross") and 2) there are important facts you want to get into evidence using the defendant.

Since the defendant is "your" witness, this limits your rights. For instance, you cannot "impeach" the defendant's testimony since you can't impeach your own witness. (Often, the case hinges on your impeaching the defendant on "cross.") Instead, the defense attorney can question the witness on "cross," (without putting up the witness for direct examination and allowing you to cross), since s/he is technically your witness.

And I was surprised to learn from Ohwilleke's answer that you can ask this witness "leading" questions as if you were on "cross" examination.

This tactic might make sense if you judge the defendant to be a "simp" who 1) cannot lie, or otherwise hurt your case and 2) may make damaging admissions that will help your case. Most defendants do not fall into that category.

Answer (score -4):

> Can a pro se plaintiff call the defendant as a witness and compel
>   testimony in a civil suit?

Apparently not. [Md Rule 3-701(e)](https://govt.westlaw.com/mdc/Document/NA3BD15C09CEA11DB9BCF9DAC28345A2A?viewType=FullText&originationContext=documenttoc&transitionType=CategoryPageItem&contextData=%28sc.Default%29) prohibits any "pretrial discovery". So does [Md 3-711](https://govt.westlaw.com/mdc/Document/NA3CCCD309CEA11DB9BCF9DAC28345A2A?viewType=FullText&originationContext=documenttoc&transitionType=CategoryPageItem&contextData=%28sc.Default%29), the "[special rules](https://www.peoples-law.org/which-court-rules-apply)" for landlord-tenant cases. And footnote 7 of [*Mostofi v. Midland Funding, 117 A.3d 639; 223 Md.App. 687(2015)*](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inmdco20150702290), although as *obiter dictum*, specifically indicates that it would not be possible to compel the defendant's agent to submit to cross-examination. It is still unclear whether that would apply to the defendants themselves.

I have not gone through all the 38 results of [this query](http://www.leagle.com/leaglesearch?exact=small%20claims&crt=Maryland) to see what other information might be useful/applicable to your situation.

Comment: Are you saying that the prohibition against pretrial discovery implies that the opposing party cannot be called as a witness?

Comment: Right? The rules for pre-trial don't usually apply to trials, at least in my experience.

Comment: @phoog Not sure. I wouldn't have thought so, but based on *Mostofi at 641* and footnote 7, I gather that it is (at most) under the court's discretion whether or not to allow the plaintiff cross-examine a witness. See how the footnote reads: "*a small claims proceeding to which the rules of evidence do not apply, Md. Rule 3-701*". I was surprised to learn this, since the rule only mentions *pretrial*. Maybe other cases would shed more light.

Comment: No. First, it has nothing to do with the defendant's "agent." Rather, it discusses the defendant's "affiant." An affiant someone who swears to an affidavit. Often, they do this in lieu of showing up to be actual in-court testimonial witnesses. The guy in this case was claiming it was unfair that he did not get to cross-examine the people who signed affidavits agreeing with the opposing party.

Comment: Footnote 7 discusses two cases cited by the individual saying it was unfair he did not get to cross-examine the affiants. One case is where a person was not allowed to cross-examine a declarant in a case where he faced civil commitment and the other is one where the court affirmed the precedent that administrative agencies adjudicating a matter must let interested parties have a reasonable right to cross-examine witnesses. It concludes by saying that neither of those cases result in a requirement for cross examining affiants in small claims court, because the rules of evidence are inapplicable

Comment: @A.fm. Good point. I did not pay enough attention and confused affiant with agent. Thanks. I still would doubt that the absence of an affidavit will necessarily prompt the judge to grant a request for cross-examination, as I gather from that footnote excerpt ("*a small claims proceeding to which the rules of evidence do not apply, Md. Rule 3-701*").

Comment: Well, you can only cross-examine someone who the other side has direct examined. OP really means he wants to call the opposing party in the lawsuit as his own witness. Or rather, if that's not what he means, that's the only way to go about doing what he's trying to do, I believe. Which goes to the point of why *pro se* litigants are walking in the courtroom's doors already disadvantaged in comparison to the opposing side.

Comment: @A.fm. Yes, there is usually a disadvantage in terms of learning curve and experience in one's first litigation, but retaining an attorney does not whatsoever guarantee that counsel will be diligent, competent, or honest either.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Same situation if you take your car to a mechanic or your heart for surgery. Mechanic and doctor, and all other people in all other jobs, are equally as vulnerable to the lapses in judgment or the purposeful malfeasances you'll find in lawyers.

Comment: @A.fm.: You're missing the point. A lawyer beat Mr. Viggers in court, therefore lawyers are generally corrupt or incompetent. That's how formal logic works.

Comment: @bdb484 Lawyer is corrupt not bc she "beat" me, but because this lawyer embarrassed herself heckling me during the entire deposition of her client so as to mess up the transcript. And one cannot have justice served when cases are presided by a narcotics felon who at hearing tells me (verbatim) "*to stay out of the way*" because Michigan "*loves anybody who's powerful*", not to mention judge's refusal to recuse from the cases despite many issues that were unearthed by the police who busted this judge with illegal drugs. Glad I am not into the rat business of protecting criminals and fraudsters.

Comment: @A.fm By comparing with physicians and car mechanics, you are minimizing the incompetence and lack of shame with which many lawyers defraud their clients. This [report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPgUMxoxFD4) is one of many examples of corrupt lawyers, with the attorney disciplinary agency looking the other way. Furthermore, retaining a lawyer is a very expensive way to keep oneself ignorant about the law and to not even know whether the person who defrauded that person is his lawyer or the judge. This is just one reason why I strongly encourage pro se litigation.

Comment: And how is *pro se* litigation working out for you? I haven't seen your case mentioned on SCOTUSblog yet.

Comment: @bdb484 On the one hand, bad from the standpoint that the SCOTUS wantonly disavowed all its babbling about the IX and XIV Amendments, and all its precedents I cited in my Petition. On the other hand, very well in that at least I did not have to waste thousands of dollars in hiring a [team of multiple "law firms"](https://www.supremecourt.gov/search.aspx?filename=/docket/docketfiles/html/public/17-1111.html) only to get a "*Petition Denied*". In other words, a team of eight lawyers was not more effective than a pro se litigant. Similar comparison with 17-1246, 17-1176, and surely many others.

Comment: @bdb484 Yes, mixing paranoia with delusion is a scary cocktail. Inaki, no, it's the same thing. There are bad actors in every area of life, every sector of employment, every sport at the Olympics, and elsewhere. If you encountered one, I'm sorry that happened, but the stuff you're saying here is both inaccurate and, were somebody to heed your advice, potentially dangerous to others.

Comment: @A.fm. If by "paranoia" and "delusion" you intend to allude me (and even if you do not), I strongly encourage you to look at the police report, excerpt of hearing transcript, court records, etc. at http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/2018/04/felon-carol-kuhnke-seeks-reelection-as.html . I agree that there are bad actors in every area of life, but when the bad actor is a felon judge, consequences are far more detrimental than a bad actor at the Olympics. No paranoia: I provide links precisely so that anyone can verify what I denounce and see by themselves what a mess the judiciary has become.

Answer (score -6):

No.  In fact, if they so choose, the defendants may not even testify at all, which will leave you out of a cross-examination.  To do otherwise is the very definition of compelled testimony and would not be allowed.

The procedure is that the plaintiff goes first and gets to call all their witness, experts, and present evidence.  Each witness is given a direct examination by you and then a cross examination by the defense (and then a re-direct and a re-cross).  After the prosection is done, then the defense can petition the judge to drop the case (it rarely happens, but it does occur... as the burden is not on the defense, if you don't sufficiently prove your case, then there's no need for the defense to go at all).  The actual people who are charged do not need to testify and their whole case doesn't even need to present evidence to refute you.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are saying the defendants must choose to testify (in my case I know they will not, I am sure of it) for there to be a cross examination. This is the source of my confusion. Let's say I call the defendant as a witness (I'm assuming I can do this), can I not ask them questions? Doesn't the right to refuse testimony only apply to criminal cases?

Comment: @coffeeguy:  Yes, the defense does not need to prove a damn thing beyond you did not meet the burden of proof in your accusation.  In fact, if this is a jury trial, the jury will explicitly be told that they cannot use the lack of the defendant's testimony as a reason to find against him.

Comment: Your answer would be correct for a criminal case, but this is not a criminal case.

Comment: Burden of proof is always on the accuser, even in a civil case.

Comment: I think @phoog is talking about the plaintiff's right to compel the defendant to testify, not about who bears the burden of proof, but you are mistaken on both points.

Comment: @bdb484 If I understand your comment correctly, you are right.  What I was in fact talking about was the defendant's right not to testify, which applies only to criminal cases.  But there is a burden of proof on the plaintiff in a civil trial: the plaintiff is in court to make a claim, and if the evidence supporting that claim is insufficient, the claim will fail even if the respondent does not rebut it.

Comment: I agree: There is *a* burden of proof on the plaintiff in a civil case. It is not correct, though, that the burden "is always on the accuser," not in civil cases, and not even in criminal cases.

Comment: Burden of proof always begins with the plaintiff. If the plaintiff meets that burden (preponderance of the evidence), the burden then shifts to the defendant to present affirmative defenses, mitigating factors, etc.

Comment: This is not true in a civil case. The privilege not to testify as a defendant is limited to criminal cases.